# Caching variable in `Class` object

Tags: ruby

I make an API call:

```
def set_youtube(user)
  Youtube.get_subscribers(user)
  Youtube.get_views(user)
end
```

Here's my service object:

```
class Youtube
  class << self
    def get_hash(user)
      ## code to return a youtube JSON hash containing subscribers and views
    end

    def get_subscribers(user)
      youtube_hash = Youtube.get_hash(user)
      ## code to return a subscriber count
    end

    def get_views(user)
      youtube_hash = Youtube.get_hash(user)
      ## code to return a view count
    end
  end
end
```

However, I find it more elegant to call the method directly on the user. I don't want to make two calls to the API to get subscribers and then get views. But I also don't want to do:

```
youtube_hash = Youtube.get_hash(user)
Youtube.get_subscribers(youtube_hash)
Youtube.get_views(youtube_hash)
```

I want to temporarily cache the variable in the instance of this object so that I can use it for both class methods. What's the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use class variables (prefixed with @@ symbols) and cache the hash, however you will then have to maintain that and it could get messy, instead I suggest using a more OO approach?

You could make it an instance of "Youtube", and cache the hash

```
class Youtube
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def hash
    @hash ||= ... #the logic used to get the user hash in your get_hash using the @user instance variable
  end

  def subscribers
    @subscribers ||= ... #the logic used to get the user subscribers in your get_subscribers however using the hash getter method which in turn uses the @hash instance variable
  end

  def views
    @views ||= ... #the logic used to get the user views in your get_views  however using the hash getter method which in turn uses the @hash instance variable
  end
end
```

Then you can do the following and it will use the cached hash:

```
yt = Youtube.new(user: user)
yt.views
yt.subscribers
```

Maybe "YoutubeUser" is a better name? Just a suggestion. This all also could be moved to the `User` model and just use the Youtube service object. For example:

```
class User
  before_create :set_youtube

  def set_youtube
    youtube = Youtube.new(self)
    self.youtube_subscribers = youtube.subscribers
    self.youtube_views = youtube.views
  end
end
```

I assume `set_youtube` is an instance method, therefore no need to pass the user, however the class method would be similar as well.

Comment: So I do have a User model, and the user has  youtube_subscriber and youtube_views columns. So the idea is that I can just call Youtube.get_views(user) when a new User is being created (it will only be called once for the user)

Comment: I don't understand "This all also could be moved to the User model and just use the Youtube service object."  I thought we were already using the Youtube service object?